# Prometheus monitoring Kubernetes Container Memory usage and report if container using more than 90%

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Looking for example how to monitor Container Memory Usage with Prometheus.

It reports all the containers ok if we using this query:

```
(container_memory_usage_bytes / container_spec_memory_limit_bytes) * 100 > 90
```

However works ok if container does not have a memory limit defined.    The the divisor is 0, and the results are +Inf, meaning that the alert triggers incorrectly since +Inf matches > 90.

Any suggestions how to properly use Container Memory Usage monitoring?

Comment: checkout https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/tree/master/alerts

Comment: I don't recall it having actual VS limit alert tho. All alerts and dashboards are available when you install this stack https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same question from a different perspective just a few days earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64168412/how-to-formulate-query-x-y-and-y-0-correctly). So far I have not found an answer. I have settled with adding another label `has_memory_limit` that I use to only alert on containers that have a limit defined.

---

**Okay, I have figured it out:**

```
((container_memory_usage_bytes / container_spec_memory_limit_bytes) != +Inf)  * 100 > 52
```

Since positive infinity, negative infinity and NaN are numbers in [Prometheus](https://www.robustperception.io/get-thee-to-a-nannary), you can simply filter them out with `!= +Inf`.